# Fetching An Image From A Server Within Map In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of data users that I pass to another component which fetch the image of each user by mapping over the list.

```
import { useState, useRef, memo } from 'react'

const NewGoalsCon = memo(props => {


  return (
      <>
          {props.data.map((el) => {
            // get the user's avatar
            async function setAvatar () {
              const url = "http://localhost:3000/api/profile/images"
              const r = await axios.get(url, {
                headers: {
                  "user-id": el.user._id,
                  "extension": el.user.avatar.extension
                }
              })
              return `data:image/${el.user.avatar.extension};base64, ${r.data}`
            }
            var avatar
            if (el.user.avatar) {
              setAvatar().then(res => avatar = res).catch(err => console.log(err))
            } else {
              avatar = avatarPlaceholder
            }
            console.log(avatar)
        
              // check if the user has an avatar before you set the avatar constant
              return (
                  <>
                    <div className='post-head-info'>
                        <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <img src={avatar} alt='' style={{ width: '60px',  border: '2px solid #E8E8E8', borderRadius: '12px' }}/>
                            <div style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }}>
                                <h1 style={{ fontFamily: 'Open Sans Medium', fontSize: '20px', marginBottom: '5px' }}>{capitalize(el.user.fName) + ' ' + capitalize(el.user.lName)}</h1>
                                <p style={{ fontSize: '11.5px', color: '#999999' }}>{getMonth(el.date.split(",")[1].trim()) + " " + el.date.split(",")[0] + ", " + el.date.split(",")[2]}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                  </>)})}
      </>)
})

  
export default NewGoalsCon
```

My problem is that the avatar keeps re-rendering when I use `useState`, and I'm trying to set `avatar` to `data:image/${el.user.avatar.extension};base64, ${r.data}` where `r.data` is the base64. I also tried using a global variable but I can't assign it `r.data`. Any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the avatar keeps re-rendering when you use `useState` is because React will re-render the component whenever the state changes, and in your current code calls `setAvatar` on each render, re-rendering the avatars each time. To fix this issue, you should cache the avatars using `useState` and use `useEffect` to only render the avatars once:

```js
import { useState, useRef, memo } from 'react';

const NewGoalsCon = memo((props) => {
  async function setAvatar(el) {
    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/profile/images';
    const r = await axios.get(url, {
      headers: {
        'user-id': el.user._id,
        extension: el.user.avatar.extension,
      },
    });
    return `data:image/${el.user.avatar.extension};base64, ${r.data}`;
  }

    const [avatars, setAvatars] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const renderedAvatars = []
            for (const el of props.data) {
                if (el.user.avatar) {
                    renderedAvatars.push(await setAvatar(el))
                } else {
                    renderedAvatars.push(avatarPlaceholder)
                }
            }

            setAvatars(renderedAvatars)
        })()
    }, [])

  return (
    <>
      {props.data.map((el, i) => {
        // check if the user has an avatar before you set the avatar constant
        return (
          <>
            <div className="post-head-info">
              <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <img
                  src={avatars[i]}
                  alt=""
                  style={{
                    width: '60px',
                    border: '2px solid #E8E8E8',
                    borderRadius: '12px',
                  }}
                />
                <div style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }}>
                  <h1
                    style={{
                      fontFamily: 'Open Sans Medium',
                      fontSize: '20px',
                      marginBottom: '5px',
                    }}
                  >
                    {capitalize(el.user.fName) +
                      ' ' +
                      capitalize(el.user.lName)}
                  </h1>
                  <p style={{ fontSize: '11.5px', color: '#999999' }}>
                    {getMonth(el.date.split(',')[1].trim()) +
                      ' ' +
                      el.date.split(',')[0] +
                      ', ' +
                      el.date.split(',')[2]}
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
});

export default NewGoalsCon;
```

You can find more detailed information at this post I wrote (including other tips for your code): https://dialect.so/blog/fetching-an-image-from-a-server-within-map-in-react